# iOS 14 App freezes when Visual="Material" in Entries with IsPassword="True"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When you are using Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material package and create a style like this:

```
<Style
    TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter
        Property="TextColor"
        Value="{StaticResource OnSurfaceColor}" />
    <Setter
        Property="PlaceholderColor"
        Value="{StaticResource OnSurfaceColor}" />
    <Setter
        Property="BackgroundColor"
        Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter
        Property="FontSize"
        Value="{StaticResource FontSizeNormal}"/>
</Style>
```

And create a layout like this:

```
<Frame
        Margin="16,24">
        <StackLayout
            Margin="4,8"
            Spacing="0">

            <Entry
                Visual="Material"
                Text="{Binding UserName}"
                Keyboard="Email"
                Placeholder="{i18n:Translate signIn_txtUserName_placeholder}" />

            <Entry  Visual="Material"
                    x:Name="txtPassword"
                    IsPassword="True"
                    Text="{Binding Password}"
                    Placeholder="{i18n:Translate signIn_txtPassword_placeholder}" />

        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
```

App freezes ... When I have changed color between entrys, but It's not work. The first that screen it work, but when I back to it, My iOS 14 App freezes . 1: Login, Screen 2: Home, From App run the first -> Login -> Home, It's work! But Form Home -> Logout back to Login, iOS 14 App freezes :((( Someone help me ?
*Please, thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Is it not work only with iOS 14?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yep, Are you have solution ? In my case, I using prism and  Visual=“Material” in Entries with IsPassword=“True”. App freeze

Comment: I think you can open an issue in Github about this problem as it probably may caused by some new feature in iOS 14.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I can fix it using style line instead style for this entry. And I don't edit the font, for example in my case, on the style had setted the font family and it doesn't like now with iOS 14... So I remove the font family for this entry and work

Comment: But my case, I using Visual Material ... Not the same you. 
The first that screen it work, but when I back to it, My iOS 14 App freezes . 1: Login, Screen 2: Home, From App run the first -> Login -> Home, It's work! But Form Home -> Logout back to Login, iOS 14 App freezes :(((

Comment: I have the same flow, welcome--> login--> home --> (logout)--> login. and I works. Try to delete all styles and then try to execute the flow. I'm using Material Design too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had to remove MaterialComponents textfields.
Looks like the issues have been solved in version 116.0 of MaterialComponents. But it's not available for some reason. Please refer : [GitHub](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/10081)